# Determine screen color depth in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, color-depth

I'm trying to determine the color depth of the screen to convert some images to RGB565 if necessary.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getPixelFormat()`.
See [getPixelFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getPixelFormat%28%29), [PixelFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html)

Comment: This is deprecated from API Level 17 (Reason:This method is no longer supported. The result is always RGBA_8888.)