# How to determine screen color depth in android

Tags: android, color-depth

I'm trying open and read '**/dev/graphics/fb0**' to determine screen color depth, but it returns error **Permission denied**.

Do you have any idea how to determine color depth of device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the fb0 is a buffer file, it is an always-changing file, you should copy it to a certain ACCESSIBLE destination then read it with `FileInputStream`,

Like:

```
("cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /dev/myRawFrame.raw");

File CurrentRawFile = new File("/dev/myRawFrame.raw");
```

[Determine screen color depth in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589607/determine-screen-color-depth-in-android)